# how to find CPU time used by each call when inside a loop?

Tags: maxima

I am learning Maxima, but having hard time finding how to obtain the cpu time used in call to integrate, when inside a loop construct.

The problem is that the function time(%o1) gives the CPU time used to compute line %o1.

But inside a loop, the whole loop is taken as one operation. So I can't use time() to time single call.

Here is an example

```
   lst:[sin(x),cos(x)];
   for i thru length(lst) do
   (
   result :  integrate( lst[i],x)
   );
```

I want to find the cpu time used for *each* call to integrate, not the cpu time used for the whole loop. Adding `showtime: true$` does not really help. I need to obtain the CPU time used for each call, and save the value to a variable.

Is there a way in Maxima to find CPU time used by each call to integrate in the above loop?

Using wxMaxima 15.04.0, windows 7.
Maxima version: 5.36.1
Lisp: SBCL 1.2.7

I was looking for something like Mathematica's [AbsoluteTiming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the function you need is `elapsed_real_time`.

EDIT: you would use  it like this:

```
for i ...
  do block ([t0, t1],
            t0 : elapsed_real_time (),
            integrate (...),
            t1 : elapsed_real_time (),
            time[i] : t1 - t0);
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of elapsed real time, which on my GCL maxima seems to return
absolute real time in seconds, try the lisp function

GET-INTERNAL-RUN-TIME

which you can call from the Maxima command line by

?get-internal-run-time();

This should return run time on any common lisp system.  In GCL,
in units of 100 per second.